# <P> fechando antes da tag </P>

Tags: php, html

Possuo o seguinte código para gerar um owl carousel dentro de uma div do site que estou a desenvolver, porem qdo vou ver no html a tag `<p>` fecha antes da div  do carousel, deixando o layout totalmente errado. Abaixo está o código que está presente no php:

```
<p class="htlfndr-hotel-thumbnail">
    <div class="owl-carousel-search owl-theme htlfndr-hotel-thumbnail">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imgModal" onclick="atualizaModal(\'thumb.php?src='.$strUrlSistema . $arrItemQuartoDisponivel['imagem'].'\');" >
              <img src="thumb.php?src=' . $strUrlSistema . $arrItemQuartoDisponivel['imagem'] . '&x=260&y=155&q=100&fill=false" alt="pic" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="thumb.php?src=' . $strUrlSistema . $arrItemQuartoDisponivel['imagem'] . '&x=260&y=155&q=100&fill=false" alt="pic" />
        </div>
     </div>
</p>
```

E abaixo está o código como é mostrado na web(Código visto pelo inspecionar elemento):[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tag `<p>` anteriormente era um `<a href>` e eu substitui ela pois eu achei que oque causou o erro era existir uma tag igual e ela dentro, porém após sua substituição o erro da tag fechando antes continuou, alguém teria alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Cara não sei te responder, mas tenta ir apagando linha por linha e ir testando, vai chegar um momento que você vai apagar uma linha (mantendo a estrutura html) que o erro vai desaparecer ai você vai saber onde está o erro e poderá buscar a solução. O esse deve ser nessas parada louca q vc arrumou ai cm o php, deve ser algum erro de string algo do tipo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tag `<p>` não permite `<div>` dentro. Conforme informa o W3C [nesta documentação](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1):

> *The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself).*
>
> O elemento P representa um parágrafo. Não pode conter elementos
>   *block-level* (inclusive o próprio P).

A `div` é considerada um elemento *block-level* ([conforme esta documentação](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#block-inline), também do W3C).

Quando você insere uma `div` em um elemento `p`, o `p` é fechado quando a `div` é aberta, e o navegador ainda adiciona outro `<p></p>` após. Exemplo:

Este código:

```
<p>
    <div>
       texto texto texto
    </div>
</p>
```

Resultará nisto:

```
<p>
</p>
<div>
    texto texto texto
</div>
<p>
</p>
```

Para solucionar isto, em lugar de `<p>`, use a própria tag `div`:

```
<div class="htlfndr-hotel-thumbnail">
    <div class="owl-carousel-search owl-theme htlfndr-hotel-thumbnail">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imgModal" onclick="atualizaModal(\'thumb.php?src='.$strUrlSistema . $arrItemQuartoDisponivel['imagem'].'\');" >
              <img src="thumb.php?src=' . $strUrlSistema . $arrItemQuartoDisponivel['imagem'] . '&x=260&y=155&q=100&fill=false" alt="pic" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="thumb.php?src=' . $strUrlSistema . $arrItemQuartoDisponivel['imagem'] . '&x=260&y=155&q=100&fill=false" alt="pic" />
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```