# Quais são os elementos permitidos dentro da tag <P>?

Tags: html, html-tags

Já passei por alguns problemas e ainda pude contemplar [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/266246/p-fechando-antes-da-tag-p) que a tag `<p>` não aceita qualquer elemento como filho.

Me parece que existem exceção de umas tags, ou seja, elas podem ser adicionadas dentro de um `<p>`, como por exemplo `<br>`, `<a>`.

Mas sempre fico na dúvida quando quero usar essa tag `<p>` sobre o que posso ou não colocar dentro dela.

Sendo assim, eu queria saber:

- Qual é o sentido de haver essa restrição da tag `<p>` não aceitar certos elementos?
- Quais são os elementos permitidos dentro de uma tag `<p>`?

**Observação**: A resposta da pergunta linkada cita que a tag `<p>` não aceita certos elementos, mas não explica por que e nem porque alguns são aceitos.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

O elemento `<p>` é categorizado como [elemento de fluxo](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2) e [elemento palpável](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#palpable-content-2), podendo, portanto, ser utilizado em qualquer lugar que é esperado um elemento de fluxo. Permite como elementos filhos qualquer elemento que seja um [elemento de frase](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2).

As definições de cada um, além dos links citados, encontra-se na W3C, 3.2 *Elements*, 3.2.5 *Content models*, 3.2.5.1 *Kinds of contents*:

- [3.2.5.1.1 Metadata content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#metadata-content-0)
- [3.2.5.1.2 Flow content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#flow-content-0)
- [3.2.5.1.3 Sectioning content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#sectioning-content-0)
- [3.2.5.1.4 Heading content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#heading-content-0)
- [3.2.5.1.5 Phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#phrasing-content-0)
- [3.2.5.1.6 Embedded content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#embedded-content-0)
- [3.2.5.1.7 Interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#interactive-content-0)

A relação entre os grupos é:

[image]

<sup>Fonte e versão da imagem iterativa: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#kinds-of-content</sup>

De forma simplificada, os elementos de frase são os elementos que definem o conteúdo da aplicação ou suas formatações - vale ressaltar a palavra formatação aqui, pois formatação não é estilização (CSS aplica estilos).

No momento, os elementos de frase são (links para a documentação você encontra [aqui](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#phrasing-content-0)):

> a, abbr, area (se for descendente de um `<map>`), audio, b, bdi, bdo,
>   br, button, canvas, cite, code, data, datalist, del, dfn, em, embed,
>   i, iframe, img, input, ins, kbd, label, link (se for permitido no
>   corpo), map, mark, MathML math, meta (se possuir o atributo
>   `itemprop`), meter, noscript, object, output, picture, progress, q,
>   ruby, s, samp, script, select, slot, small, span, strong, sub, sup,
>   svg, template, textarea, time, u, var, video, wbr, *autonomous custom
>   elements* e *text*.

Se outros elementos forem adicionados como filhos do `<p>`, é possível que o elemento seja fechado antes do esperado quando o cliente processar a estrutura do HTML, tal como o Rafael comentou em [sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/313321/5878).

A especificação cita explicitamente, inclusive, o exemplo de definir listas dentro de um parágrafo, onde não é possível utilizar os elementos `<ol>` e `<ul>` dentro de `<p>`.

```css
p > ul {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
</p>
```

O HTML interpretado será:

```
<p></p>
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
<p></p>
```

Tanto que o CSS, que define a fonte vermelha para um elemento `ul` dentro de um `p` não funcionou. Neste caso, o ideal é, assim como foi interpretado, gerar dois parágrafos distintos, um antes e outro depois da lista ou definir o conteúdo dentro de outro elemento, assim como a `div`.

```html
<div>For instance, this fantastic sentence has bullets relating to
<ul>
 <li>wizards,
 <li>faster-than-light travel, and
 <li>telepathy,
</ul>
and is further discussed below.</div>
```

Que será interpretado exatamente da maneira que está.

Answer (score 10):

A tag `<p>` define um parágrafo.

É permitido dentro da tag `<p>` qualquer conteúdo de texto simples e marcações, como:
`<abbr>, <audio>, <b>, <bdo>, <br>, <button>, <canvas>, <cite>, <code>, <command>, <data>, <datalist>, <dfn>, <em>, <embed>, <i>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <kbd>, <keygen>, <label>, <mark>, <math>, <meter>, <noscript>, <object>, <output>, <progress>, <q>, <ruby>, <samp>, <script>, <select>, <small>, <span>, <strong>, <sub>, <sup>, <svg>, <textarea>, <time>, <var>, <video>, <wbr>`

Caso você insira dentro da tag `<p>` algum elemento como: 
`<address>, <article>, <aside>, <blockquote>, <div>, <dl>, <fieldset>, <footer>, <form>, <h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5>, <h6>, <header>, <hr>, <menu>, <nav>, <ol>, <pre>, <section>, <table>, <ul>`

O parágrafo será automaticamente fechado. Vejamos no exemplo:

```html
<p> teste <div> div </div> </p>
```

Analisando o código fonte, a tag `<p>` será fechada automaticamente.

```
<p> teste </p>
 <div> div </div>
<p></p>
```

**Fontes**:  [O elemento Parágrafo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p), [Conteúdo com texto permitido](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content), [W3C](https://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#phrasing-content).

Answer (score -1):

É por questão de semântica web.

O "p" vem de parágrafo, por isso, espera-se que o conteúdo dessa tag tenha texto corrido e, talvez, no máximo, tags de formatação de texto, embora isto possa ser feito mais adequadamente com CSS.

Comment: _"espera-se que o conteúdo dessa tag tenha texto corrido"_ Quem espera isso? E o que tem a ver CSS com os elementos da pergunta?