# Na <label> é semântico ou permitido usar quais elementos dentro?

Tags: html, html5, semântica, acessibilidade

Estudando vi alguns exemplos de código onde o `input` é colocado dentro da `label`, isso me trouxe uma dúvida, seria semântico usar quais elementos dentro de uma `label`?

```
<label for="campo">Descritivo do campo
   <input type="text" id="campo" />
</label>
```

A tag `<label>` não deveria ser apenas para oferecer um descritivo do campo a seguir?

Em termos de acessibilidade eu posso usar elementos de título tipo `H2` ou `H3` dentro de uma `label`? Semanticamente isso parece errado... Fico imaginando o leitor de tela encontrando um título `h2` dentro de uma `label`

```
<label for="campo">
   <h2>título do campo</h2>
   <input type="text" id="campo" />
</label>
```

**O que seria o correto de se usar dentro da label?**

O que seria válido pela W3C ou WCGA?

Comment: Não sei se é certo, mas [olha aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4461962/7437072)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#the-label-element) e [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element), o conteúdo permitido é qualquer elemento caracterizado como [*phrasing content*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2), que é o mesmo permitido para o elemento `<p>`.

- [Quais são os elementos permitidos dentro da tag <P>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313303/5878)

Porém, não será permitido elementos que são rotuláveis (*labelable*), tal como `<input>`, com uma exceção em particular. O elemento `<label>` possui o atributo `for` que pode receber o `id` do `<input>` ao qual está associado. Neste caso, o `<label>` já possui uma entrada de controle e, portanto, não poderá possuir outras em seu conteúdo. Assim, se utilizar o atributo `for`, não poderá definir `<input>` no seu conteúdo.

Já, quando o atributo `for` não for utilizado, será considerado como entrada de controle o primeiro campo rotulável de seu conteúdo. Neste caso, o primeiro `<input>` que encontrar dentro de `<label>`. Desta forma, não utilizando o atributo, você poderá ter um, e apenas um, elemento rotulável como filho.

Os elementos caracterizados como *phrasing content* são:

> a, abbr, area (se for descendente de um `<map>`), audio, b, bdi, bdo, br, button, canvas, cite, code, data, datalist, del, dfn, em, embed, i, iframe, img, input, ins, kbd, label, link (se for permitido no corpo), map, mark, MathML math, meta (se possuir o atributo  `itemprop`), meter, noscript, object, output, picture, progress, q, ruby, s, samp, script, select, slot, small, span, strong, sub, sup, svg, template, textarea, time, u, var, video, wbr, autonomous custom elements e text.

Bem como os elementos rotuláveis são:

> button, input (se não for do tipo *hidden*), meter, output, progress, select, textarea

Comment: Valeu pelo esclarecimento jovem!