# Como estilizar um input do tipo checkbox?

Tags: css3, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, bootstrap-4

Estou criando múltiplas seleções com o `checkbox` e preciso deixa-lo com as seguintes características:

- Background transparente
- Estilizar as bordas
- Remover o Check

Isto para que ele fique por cima dos meus .card e o usuário pense que está clicando em um cartão, quando na verdade é um `checkbox` e esta ativando ou desativando aquela opção.

Já tentei editar com as propriedades das mesmas e nada acontece, segue o código:

```
<div class="form-group col-3 mt-2">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="font-weight-bold ml-1">Selecione seus Títulos Acadêmicos</label>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <div class="position-absolute mt-2 ml-1"
            style="width: 15rem; height: 11.6rem; border: 1px red solid; z-index: 1 !important">
            <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input"
                style="background-color: transparent !important; width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important;">
        </div>
        <div class="position-relative" style="z-index: 0 !important">
            <div class="card py-2 pb-4 mt-2 ml-1" style="width: 15rem">
                <div class="card-header pb-0 border-0 bg-transparent text-center">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Pós Graduação</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap" style="font-size: 4rem"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Figura Ilustrativa:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jovem primeiro cria um `input:checkbox` e coloca nele a classe `sr-only`, essa classe é original do BS4 e serve para o elemento só ficar visível par *ScreenReaders*

Depois no seu CSS vc cria uma regra para quando esse `checkbox` estive `:checked` ele vai colocar uma classe no elemento que vier abaixo dele, no caso o `.card`. Ficaria assim: `#meubtn:checked+label>.card { }`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora envolva o seu card com uma `<label>` com a classe `.none`, criei essa classe para tentar limpar qq estilo `default` que o Bootstrap por ventura possa ter colocada por padrão nas `labels`. Essa `label` vai ter um for="" para o `input:checkbox sr-only` que vai ativar o estilo CSS quando estiver `:checked`

Segue o código da imagem acima. Não tem JS aqui é só CSS.

```css
#meubtn:checked+label>.card {
  background-color: red;
}
label.none {
  all: unset !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  
<div class="form-group col-3 mt-2">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="font-weight-bold ml-1">Selecione seus Títulos Acadêmicos</label>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <input type="checkbox" id="meubtn" class="sr-only">
    <label for="meubtn" class="none">
      <div class="card py-2 pb-4 mt-2 ml-1" style="width: 15rem">
        <div class="card-header pb-0 border-0 bg-transparent text-center">
          <h5 class="card-title">Pós Graduação</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body text-center">
          <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap" style="font-size: 4rem"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Não sabia que podia botar outros elementos a não ser o input dentro do label.

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS pode por vários tipos de elemento dentro de uma label, eu mesmo ja perguntei sobre isso aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/325806/na-label-%c3%a9-sem%c3%a2ntico-ou-permitido-usar-quais-elementos-dentro