# Como fazer o label funcionar com um link dentro?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Como fazer que quando ao clicar no link o checkbox também fique selecionado?

Segue trecho do código abaixo:

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
iframe {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='ch' />

<label for='ch'>
  <a href='https://dottcon.com' target='conteudo'>Site</a>
</label>

<iframe name='conteudo'></iframe>
```

Preciso que ao clicar no link a caixa de seleção seja marcada ou desmarcada dependendo do estado atual dela.

Obs: Se possível gostaria de não usar JS.

Comment: Esse tipo de controle vc só vai conseguir com JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não precisa de JS mesmo não, mas isso me parece tão errado quanto de fato deve ser.

Não vejo motivo estrutural, e muito menos semântico para usar um `link` dentro de um `label`! Até pq o seu `label` tem um `for`, ou seja, tem um uma entrada de controle... Recomendo fortemente que leia isso: [Na <label> é semântico ou permitido usar quais elementos dentro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/325806/na-label-%c3%a9-sem%c3%a2ntico-ou-permitido-usar-quais-elementos-dentro)

Mas caso queira seguir com isso, basta usar uma combinação de `z-index -1` e um `tabindex -1` no `link`,  assim quando vc clicar nele na realidade vc vai estar clicando na `label`, que por sua vez já tem um  `for='ch'` para o `checkbox` resultando no que vc deseja.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com o `z-index -1` e `tabindex -1` o link fica inacessível tanto para o mouse quanto para o teclado, então vc não consegue fazer o `focus` nele, e quando clicar vai clicar na verdade na `label`, não no link que está "bloqueado"

---

**EDIT**

<sup>*Vou complementar com algumas informações, pois para mim não tinha ficado claro que ele queria carregar o iFrame, achei que ele queria apenas marcar o checkbox clicando no link*</sup>

Primeiro vou deixar claro uns detalhes, para ficar exatamente como no código que está na pergunta, ou seja, mesmos sem o `iframe` estar carregado ele ocupa um espaço na tela, então eu coloquei nele `visibility:hidden`, e tb usei um atributo novo chamado `loading="lazy"`, com isso mesmo sem o `iframe` aparecer na tela ela ocupa o espaço correspondente, e só vai ser carregado em background sob demanda devido ao `lazy load`, com isso a página não fica muito pesada.

Então vc não precisa da lógica `target/name`, e deixe o `src` correto no `iframe` *(apesar disso eu ainda deixei os atributos lá para vc ver que uma coisa não interfere na outra)*

Depois, o seu `iframe` tem um `frameborder`, para eu garantir que a borda vai aparecer, mesmo sem o `iframe` estar visível, eu precisei colocar o `iframe` dentro de uma `div` com a classe `.box`. Nessa `div.box` eu coloquei os mesmo estilos de borda do `user-agent` e no `iframe` eu coloquei `frameborder="0"`. Agora mesmo sem o iframe estar visível ele ainda tem as bordas.

Agora para "ativar" o `iframe` caso cliquei no `link` eu usei uma regra simples de seletores CSS `input:checked ~ .box > iframe{ visibility: visible; }` Desse forma se o `checkbox` receber o `cheked` ele vai procurar o primeiro elemento irmão abaixo que tenha a classe `.box` e dentro do `.box` o `iframe` e vai setar o elemento com`o visible`.

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
iframe {
  /* margin-top: 20px; */
  width: 100%;

  visibility: hidden;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

input:checked ~ .box > iframe{
  visibility: visible;
}
.box {
  margin-top: 20px;

  display: flex;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: inset;
  border-color: initial;
  border-image: initial;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='ch' />

<label for='ch'>
  <a tabindex="-1" href='https://dottcon.com' target='conteudo'>Site</a>
</label>

<div class="box">
  <iframe src="https://dottcon.com" name='conteudo' loading="lazy" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Foi quase, mas ao realizar o click o link também tem que abrir no iframe. No caso que você colocou eu só consigo fazer a seleção do chekbox.

Comment: @AllanMax entendi jovem, é que para mim não tinha ficado claro que vc queria carregar o iframe, para mim vc queria só marcar o checkbox clicando no link... De qq forma, leia o **EDIT** que fiz ai na resposta, tem alguns detalhes, mas não é difícil de entender. Tudo só com CSS/HTML, e otimizado para não pesar de mais a tela caso vc tenha outros iframes mais para baixo

Answer (score 1):

Eu também acho que isso so vai ser possível com javascript então eu mudei um pouco o html e fiz um script.

```js
function showFrame() {
  const frame = document.getElementsByName("conteudo")[0];
  const checkbox = document.getElementById("ch");

  if (checkbox.checked) {
    frame.src = "https://dottcon.com";
  } else {
    //quando o checkbox nao estiver selecionado fazer alguma coisa
  }

}
```

```html
<a href='#' target='conteudo' onclick="showFrame();">
  <input type='checkbox' id='ch' />
  <label for='ch'>
          Site
        </label></a>
<iframe name='conteudo'></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sem JavaScript você não vai conseguir o que deseja. Como o @hugocss disse, colocar um link dentro do label não é a melhor ideia.

Você pode deixar o label normal, sem link, apenas um texto que você pode indicar sendo um link (colocando `cursor: pointer`, por exemplo), e abrir a página que deseja dentro do iframe de outra forma, utilizando JavaScript e atributos *dataset*, como `data-url` e `data-target`.

Como o link é filho do label e este possui um `for` diretamente relacionado ao `id` do checkbox, fica fácil encontra-lo ao clicar no label. Basta usar um `event handler` de click pegando o valor de `for` da label pai e buscar o respectivo checkbox com o mesmo `id` desse `for`:

```js
// seleciona todos os checkbox
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']");
// seleciona todos os label
const labels = document.querySelectorAll("label");

// cria event handlers para os checkbox
for(let i of boxes){
   i.onclick = function(){
      let id = this.getAttribute("id"); // pega o id do checkbox clicado
      // procura um label com um "for" igual ao id
      let label = document.querySelector("[for='"+id+"']");
      // se existir, chama a função enviando o label como parâmetro
      if(label) controle(label);
   }
}

// cria event handlers para os label
for(let i of labels){
   i.onclick = function(){
      let id = this.getAttribute("for"); // pega o "for" do label clicado
      // procura um checkbox com um id igual ao "for"
      let box = document.querySelector("#"+id);
      // se existir, chama a função enviando o label como parâmetro
      if(box) controle(i);
   }
}

function controle(label){
   
   let id = label.getAttribute("for"); // pega o "for" da label
   let url = label.dataset.url; // pega o data-url
   let target = label.dataset.target; // pega o data-target
   let box = document.getElementById(id); // pega o checkbox pelo id
   
   if(box.checked){
      // se o box for marcado, abrir a URL no iframe
      document.querySelector("[name='"+target+"']").src = url;
   }else{
      // faz algo quando o checkbox estiver desmarcado, como esvaziar o iframe
      document.querySelector("[name='"+target+"']").src = "";
   }
   
}
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}
label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}
iframe {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='ch' />
<label for='ch' data-url="https://dottcon.com" data-target="conteudo">
  Site
</label>
<iframe name='conteudo'></iframe>
```