# Para que serve as categorias de conteúdo?

Tags: html

Recentemente eu descobri que no *HTML5* existem categorias que são chamadas de *Content categories* (categorias de conteúdo) e são elas:

- **Metadata content**
- **Flow content**
- **Sectioning content**
- **Heading content**
- **Phrasing content**
- **Embedded content**
- **Interactive content**
- **Palpable content**
- **Form-associated content**
- **Script-supporting elements**

**Fonte**: [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content)

Eu gostaria de saber para que servem essas categorias? e como usá-las?

Comment: Me parece que elas servem apenas como uma forma de guia sobre como os elementos HTML devem ser utilizados. i.e Sectioning Content deve ser usado para seccionar (separar/dividir) a sua página HTML em partes (cabeçalho, menu, corpo, etc..).

Comment: O que você entende por "como usá-las"? É comum categorizar-se os tipos de elementos que uma determinada tag pode receber, tal como [Quais são os elementos permitidos dentro da tag <P>?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/313319/5878) É esse tipo de uso que se refere?

Comment: Elas não são usadas por vc, elas são usadas para documentar. Cada elemento do html vai ser categorizado de acordo com suas propriedades e uso dentro de cada grupo desses

Comment: Woss, não era isso era sobre o que são essas categorias

Comment: Hugocsl, então só serve para organizar os elementos?

Comment: Se sim! então porque o elemento `<caption>` não está nessas categorias?

Answer (score 1):

A [documentação do HTML5](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#categorieshttps://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#categories) descreve as Categorias de Conteúdo desta maneira:

> Cada elemento no HTML cai em zero ou mais categorias que agrupam elementos com características semelhantes.

Se você ler esse documento, verá que essas categorias organizam, falando a grosso modo, os elementos com os quais você irá trabalhar na marcação de uma página. É como se ele tivesse te falando *"Olha, você pode marcar o HTML como você quiser, mas nem tudo é da maneira que você espera que seja. E, para facilitar sua vida, organizamos os elementos de acordo com suas funções e características em relação a outros elementos."*

Por exemplo, vejamos a categoria Heading Content.

> **4.1.5 Heading content**
>   Heading content includes the elements for marking up headers. Headings, in conjunction with the sectioning elements, are used to describe the the structure of the document.
>   Heading content includes the `header` element and the `h1` to `h6` elements.
>   *Elements categorised as heading content are considered to be flow content.*

Aqui temos a descrição dos elementos que compõe o conteúdo de cabeçalho. Quer dizer que nesta categoria, você deve usar os elementos que pertencem a ela para fazer o que realmente deve fazer, que é definir cabeçalhos ou títulos nos trechos do documento que se fizerem necessários. Em outras palavras, você deve marcar um título ou um bloco cabeçalho com os elementos que foram designados para tal. Por exemplo, na composição de um layout comumente temos um *navbar*, *sidebar*, `main` e `footer`. Mas, geralmente, muitos não marcam *navbar* no elemento `header`.

Muitos desenvolvedores consideram usar `footer`, mas não `header`. E a fatos como esse que as Categories content tentam nos esclarecer. Veja:

> 4.3.4.8 The footer element
>  The footer element represents a footer of a section, typically containing information such as who wrote it, links to related documents, and copyright notices.

Exatamente antes de footer, temos

> 4.3.4.7 The header element
>  The header element represents the header of a section, typically containing headings and subheadings, and other metadata about the section.

A descrição desses elementos ainda nos ajuda a entender o papel deles no contexto da marcação HTMLde um modo geral.

Pense nessas categorias como conjuntos e subconjuntos. Sendo que alguns elementos não pertencem a nenhum conjunto específico. Outros pertencem a mais de um conjunto, como no caso de Heading content *"Elements categorised as heading content **are considered to be flow content**"*.

Finalmente, essas categorias nos orientam a escrever um HTML mais correto e coerente, usando os elementos de acordo com as funções para as quais eles foram criados para desempenhar.